# What is this plant with compound leaves growing in Central-Maine?

Tags: identification, shrubs

A friend of mine in Maine sent me this picture of a plant in her yard to identify.  She is worried it might be Poison Sumac, but I have my doubts.  Sorry, only one picture.  Zone 5

[image]

Comment: Do not believe it is poisonous sumac.  The poisonous plant has smooth or entire leaf margins.  This one is serrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is Smooth Sumac unless my eyes are seeing serration that is not there.  Here is a link for Smooth Sumac, a boon to wildlife.  [smooth sumac](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jsY7G-2z-w4/VNmz4LM7aII/AAAAAAAAEEo/4WkjAdYBATo/s1600/sumac1.jpg)

Comment: @pnuts I like that website. I haven't seen it before. There are a lot of interesting articles and good pictures. Thanks for introducing me to that!

Comment: Ahhhh!  Shoot, didn't notice.  You have noticed that once you reach a certain point, points begin to snowball?  All that work does keep coming up and makes sense to someone else.  Thanks, pnuts.  And I've probably got the highest amount of negative points as well!  And that is a good thing, too.

Comment: @stormy, I bet you don't have the most negative rep (downvotes) of anyone! Also people you think have no downvotes have at least some. Nobody's perfect here!

Comment: I thought everyone knew that perfection is not real and trying to be perfect is a waste of time.  Trying to be humble and real is as perfect as we are able to be.  Good grief...sorry!!